# MongoJS find is too specific

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mongojs

I am trying to query my mongoDB database in my MEAN Stack web application by sending in a POST request with the values I want to find in the database.

Here is what I'm doing :

```
app.post('/api/persons',function(req,res){
    console.log("I received a POST request on the DB. Querying :");
    console.log(req.body);
    db.persons.find(req.body,function(err,doc){
        if(err){
            console.log("The request didn't work:"+err+".");
        }else{
            res.json(doc);
            console.log("The request was successful.")
        }
    });
})
```

The code works, but only if I enter the exact value.

For example, if I search for a person that is 22 years old, I will find only the document { "age": 22 } and not the document { "name": "Catarina", "age": 22 }.

If I search for a 22 Y.O. person the object sended is

```
 Object {age:22}
```

How can I get all the related documents to the query?

EDIT: these datas are not the one I use anymore, please see under

EDIT2: I guess the problem is that the value sent in the req.body is nested. Is it possible to automatically change

```
{ physiological_data: { age: 5, gender: 'M' } }
```

to

```
{ 'physiological_data.age':5, 'physiological_data.gender':'M' } ???
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you show your POST request data ?

Comment: hey, thanks, I changed it, please see in the answer under ;)

Answer (score 1):

use empty {} in query.

```
app.post('/api/persons',function(req,res){
    db.persons.find({}, req.body,function(err,doc){
        if(err){
            console.log("The request didn't work:"+err+".");
        }else{
            res.json(doc);
            console.log("The request was successful.")
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, but I get : The request didn't work:MongoError: >1 field in obj: {}.

Comment: i need to view req.body, can you post here?

Comment: yes, actually, I changed my values and the req.body is `{ evaluation: {},
  exams: {},
  setup: {},
  physiological_data: { age: 5, gender: 'M' } }`
In my DB, the value I want to find is exactly like that but the fields of evaluation, exams and setup are not empty

Comment: ok, now the query works if I manage to send { physiological_data: { age: 5, gender: 'M' } } I get everything. But why if I try to send { evaluation:{S1:"present"},physiological_data: { age: 5, gender: 'M' }} it doesn't work even if there is one in the DB? It seems it doesn't work if I forget one field in one bracket. For example if I just do { physiological_data: { age: 5 } } it won't show me anything

Comment: I guess the problem is that the value is nested. Is it possible to automatically change `{ physiological_data: { age: 5, gender: 'M' } }` to `{ 'physiological_data.age':5, 'physiological_data.gender':'M' }` ???

Comment: I tried to stringify the thing, but the query selector must be an object .... The stringification works though and gives a string with the perfect request.